# Can a PDA be the owner of an associated token account?

Tags: pda, token, mint, ata

```
SPL.createAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, wallet, mint, project, {skipPreflight: true}, undefined, SPL.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID).then((projectTokenAccount) => {
      const mintIx = SPL.createMintToInstruction(mint, projectTokenAccount, wallet.publicKey, 2500000, undefined, undefined)

      const tx = new Transaction().add(mintIx)

      connection.sendTransaction(tx, [wallet], {skipPreflight: true}).then((signature) => {
            console.log(signature)
      })
})
```

When I set

```
project = new PublicKey("A PROGRAM Pubkey")
```

everything gets created and unlogically I can create an ATA with a PROGRAM as an owner (which can't sign CPI for itself).

when I set

```
project = new PublicKey("<A PDA which owner is the above PROGRAM>")
```

Then It give me an error: TokenOwnerOffCurveError

Shouldn't I be able to manage ATA from a program by creating PDAs first to associate them univoquely to a Mint ? But I can't create ATA for those PDA (my PDA have as seed the mint in order to make them univoque for each mint)

Edit: Solved It using the function getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount which allows me to set `allowOwnerOffCurve = true`

But what is the motivation behind this `allowOwnerOffCurve` necessity?

Comment: The error says it all.

Comment: To create an ATA for a PDA you can set the `allowOwnerOffCurve` to true for getAssociatedTokenAddress function once you have the address you can call `createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction` you also have the option to create the ATA from the program itself

Comment: @Pratik.js's answer is correct -- could you turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

To create an ATA for a PDA you can set the allowOwnerOffCurve to true for getAssociatedTokenAddress function once you have the address you can call createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction you also have the option to create the ATA from the program itself