# How do I transfer SPL-token programmatically when the recipient is the transaction signer?

Tags: spl-token, pda, transfer, ata

I want to transfer my custom SPL-token programmatically from my **vault** (source token account) to **George** (user destination token account), where the transaction *caller-payer is George*. Hence, I must use a PDA, but I'm struggling to create and invoke my PDA correctly. Unlike [#1](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/how-to-create-ata-associated-token-account-for-a-pda-program-derived-address?rq=1), [#2](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/does-a-pda-have-to-be-owned-by-its-signer), [#3](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/can-a-pda-be-the-owner-of-an-associated-token-account), I'm coding in native Solana Rust - NO Anchor.

What I have:

- token mint account
- source token account (ATA)
- source token account holder (pubKey)
- destination token account (ATA)

My Solana program:

```
    invoke_signed(
        &spl_token::instruction::transfer(
            token_program.key,
            vault_ata.key,
            george_ata.key, 
            pda.key,
            &[], //no signer keys, because the signer is the PDA
            amount
        )?,
        &[vault_ata.clone(), george_ata.clone(), pda.clone()],
        &[
            &[b"myseeds", b"here"] //PDA seeds
        ]
    )?;
    msg!("Transfer succeeded!");

    Ok(())
```

Questions:

1. WHERE shall I derive the PDA? In the *same* Solana program that performs the transfer **OR** in a separate program?
2. Ultimately, the PDA must sign on the vault's behalf and transfer SPL-tokens. Should I transfer the ownership of the vault to the PDA? If so, how? **OR** should I rather transfer tokens from vault to PDA (and later from PDA to George's ATA)? If so, how?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still include the signer keys argument as `&[&pda.key]`, it doesn't matter that the signer in this case is a pda. Also, you probably should include the token_program in your accounts.

Lastly derive your seeds like this:

```
&[&[b"myseeds", b"here",&[bump]][..]]
```

You need to derive the bump somehow and pass it as one of the signer seeds. Usually it's stored in the pda itself, during its creation, for use later.

Your final code should look like this:

```
invoke_signed(
    &spl_token::instruction::transfer(
        token_program.key,
        vault_ata.key,
        george_ata.key, 
        pda.key,
        &[&pda.key]
        amount
    )?,
    &[
        vault_ata.clone(), 
        george_ata.clone(), 
        pda.clone(), 
        token_program.clone()
    ],
    &[&[b"myseeds", b"here",&[bump]][..]],   
)?;

msg!("Transfer succeeded!");

Ok(())
```

PS: If you're using `Buffer.from("myseeds", "utf8")` in your testing code then the on-chain seed should be specified as `b"myseeds".as_ref()`. I have no way to tell if the way you're currently doing it is purposeful or not.